# Creating slider (using slick)

Tags: jquery, css

i want to create slider by using slick-slider.  I want to have 3 slides, the center one should be zoomed, and the rest should be visible in the background, (50% of their width should be hided behind the center slide). The problem is, when i want to have only 3 slides, slider dont work (if more its fine), also i have problems with positioning the slides in the background slides.

```
.slick-current {
    transform: scale(1.75);
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
    });
});
```

---

```
  <div class="slider">
      <div><img src="img/example.png"></div>
      <div><img src="img/example.png"></div>
      <div><img src="img/example.png"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think what you need is slik slider with center mode. Did you check out the demos in [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: thanks for answer ! i tried to use center mode, but as i said i want to have all 3 slides visible, and when i try to use center mode with **"slidesToShow: 3** it stops working. I found some info about similar problems, and author said that this kind of sliders should be done by using slickGoTo but not really sure how to do that even after reading doc.